# Как поменять название Activity в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как поменять название в ActionBar'е для Activity? В интернете нашёл что-то вроде добавления/изменения
android:label="text" в AndroidManifest.xml для Activity и это помогает, текст на activity действительно меняется, но так же меняется и название самого приложения (иконки в списке приложения) на label, указанный для MainActivity. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было каждому activity сверху добавлять свой собственный текст, но при этом чтобы название самого приложения не менялось?

Comment: ``android:label`` нужно менять (а скорее всего даже добавить, потому что автоматически оно не добавляется) внутрь activity, а не application.

Comment: @Эникейщик менял внутри activity, все равно меняет название приложени

Comment: Заголовок можно менять в коде самой активности методом `setTitle()`

Comment: @woesss мне нужно максимально правильное и грамотное решение

Comment: приложите манифест

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setTitle("My title");

        // или строку из ресурсов
        setTitle(R.string.my_title);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно открыть string.xml и добавить туда, так скажем строку:
   Your Name
2. Откройте Manifest.xml и в нужной Activity добавь атрибут:
   android:label = "app_name2"; // к примеру

Comment: Этот вариант уже описан в самом вопросе и там же поясняется почему он не устроил автора.

Comment: А еще вопрос по теме : по setTitle длинное название обрезается. Как сделать чтобы было в две строки? Ну ли уменьшить размер текста?